# SwiperJS css animation disable swipe function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, swiper.js

I want to add some animation to swiperjs to tell user this slider has swipe function and you can swipe to slide, animation working good but it conflict with swiperjs default swiping function, and you can not swipe slides, is there any solution to fix this?

```js
var swiper = new Swiper(".mySwiper", {
  slidesPerView: 3,
});
```

```css
.swiper-wrapper {
  transition-duration: 0ms;
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  animation: example 5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  50% {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  75% {
  transform: translate3d(-20px, 0px, 0px);
  }
  100% {
  transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

move the animation to the parent element

```
.swiper {
  animation: example 5s infinite alternate;
}
```